# Special result in setupFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

```
   +-----------+           +-----------+  
   | -Parada-  |           | -Autobus- |  
   +-----------+           +-----------+ 
   |  nombre   |           | circuito  | 
  +-------------+         +-------------+  
  |Relationships|         |Relationships|  
  +-------------+         +-------------+   
   |  byParada |<--------> |  parada   |
   +-----------+           +-----------+
```

I'm trying fetch a list of Paradas based on the relation between the circuitos.

For Ex:

```
 Autobus 1 has Circuito=1 and Parada=Town
 Autobus 2 has Circuito=2 and Parada=City
 Autobus 3 has Circuito=3 and Parada=Coast
 Autobus 4 has Circuito=4 and Parada=Park
```

So I'm trying to get a list of Paradas that have a higher circuit from defined, it's not easy to explain, but in my app you have two pickers with the same list of Parada s, depending of what Parada you selected in the first Picker, the second will show only the Parada s that have an higher Circuito.

For example, if in the first picker you selected "City", the second picker will let you choose "Coast" or "Park".

Here's the code i'm trying to fix:

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 0 - Ensure you have a MOC
    if (!self.managedObjectContext) {
        NSLog(@"RolePickerTVCell wasn't given a Managed Object Context ... so it's going to go get one itself!");
        RCAppDelegate *ad = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.managedObjectContext = ad.managedObjectContext;
    }

    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Parada"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"RolePickerTVCell is Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    // Here's the problem:

    NSString *predString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ANY byParada.circuito > '%@'", self.fetchedResultsController];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predString];

    // It shows nothing...
    NSLog(@"list of Paradas: %@", self.fetchedResultsController);



    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"nombre"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

    NSLog(@"The following roles were fetched for the Picker by ORIGENPickerTVCell:");
    for (Parada *fetchedOrigen in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
        NSLog(@"List of Paradas: %@", fetchedOrigen.nombre);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate setup is wrong.
The formatting should take place at the predicate construction level:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"byParada.circuito > %@",currentCircuitoAsNSNumber];
```

Where `currentCircuitoAsNSNumber` is the currently selected "circuito", and is of type `NSNumber`.

Comment: The problem is that currentCircuitoAsNSNumber must be automatic, how can I get if I only know nombre?

Comment: You explained thad you select "City", that would mean that you have access to: `byParada.cicuito` of the related `Autobus` object, or you might have given a wrong representation of your data model ...

Comment: I can only select Parada, but I don't know how to transform the name of the Parada ( Town, City... ) into its currentCircuitoAsNSNumber so then I can fetch it.

Comment: You must create some kind of enumeration system (instead of keeping the "name" of the Parada, keep a number and make the translation in your application level). if there is a One-to-One mapping between `Autobus.circuito` and the related `Parada.nombre` you can use that. when selecting a `Parada` keep its related `Autobus.nombre`